# Imported images no longer reflect on glass or glossy shader

Tags: glass

I'm modeling a house and I imported an image to be the reflected in the windows. I put it behind the camera so it can be seen in the refection of the windows. It worked fine but then for some unknown reason the image is no longer reflecting in the glass or glossy shader. Other objects reflect but not the imported bitmap. I just copied the objects to a new blender file and they reflect now so it must be something off with the original file settings, not the settings on the objects or lights or camera. Also the light is a lot harsher in the new file even though I copied all of the same lights and the camera from the original. Maybe I accidentally clicked a shortcut that changed a setting. Has this happened to anyone or does anyone have an idea what setting for reflections doesn't transfer when coping objects between files. Thanks

[image: no reflection example]

This is how it looks now in the original file

[image: reflection example]

This is how it looks after I copy the contents of the file into a blank file. You can now see the bitmap in the reflection. This is also how the reflections used to look in the original file

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For some reason the material was set to a mix shader. So the image was showing up in the view port, but not when rendered. I disconnected the mix shader and just made it a diffuse shader with the image.